# take text input from uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

i am developing an application where i need to take text input from user using sectioned table view.
i had never use table view for taking text input from user.
please have a look at the image for batter understanding.

[image]

i tried this [In-place editing of text in UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123740/in-place-editing-of-text-in-uitableviewcell/)

but this is not full filling what i wanted to.

when i use following code i get output which is not similar to above image.

```
UITextField *txtField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    txtField.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    txtField.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtField setPlaceholder:@"Type Data Here"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [cell addSubview:txtField];
```

[image]

see the answer of question 3 and 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is the link you posted not fulfilling? Please, explain a bit more in detail what you trying to achieve...

Comment: @sergio : Hi, when i use the code given in link i used for solving my query, i dont see the behaviour same to as shown in image i posted in my question. that's what my concern to post the question.

Comment: can you explain what are the difference in the behaviour? Could you post also the exact code you are using for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this would help a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add `UITextField` to content view Corresponding cell, where you want the Text field.
You select the cell you want by looking in to the cells `indexpath.section` and `indexpath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Example:

```
if(indexPath.section == CELL_SECTION) {
    if(indexpath.row == CELL_ROW_INDEX) {
      UITextField *txtField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, 39)];
      txtField.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
      txtField.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
      txtField.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;
      [txtField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
      [txtField setPlaceholder:@"Type Data Here"];
      [cell.contentView addSubView:textField];
   }
}
```

Comment: @iPhonePrg : Hi i used the same code from what i tried first, but the issue with this code is it adds simple text field, its behavior is not similar to what i suggest in my question.

Comment: what does this line do? txtField.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: Last line should be `[cell.contentView addSubview:txtField];`

Answer (score 1):

First thing first

1. you need to make a subClass of `UITableViewCell`.
2. Ofcoures that class will have a
   TextField(TF) as a property to
   access that TF
3. set tag for that TF while
   initialising it.
4. in the delegate method
   `tableView:celForRowAtIndexPath:`
   get that TF by tag use method   tf =
   [cell viewWithTag:YOUR_TAG];
5. Now you can do what ever you want.
6. Now suppose you want the value
   outside this method then there are
   two way around it

   a. make a global variable and store value in it

   b. First find the cell by method of tableView by cellforRowAtIndexPath and repeate the step 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextfield` in it. You can probably set a `tag` for the `textField` for each cell to identify them. You can also implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` if you want some validation on text or something. You can then get the value for the `textfield` based on the tag.