# In-place editing of text in UITableViewCell in iOS 5?

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, nstableviewcell

I know this question has been answered before, the answer below looks pretty good.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4124023/1098059

However, most of the answers date from before iOS 5. With the new static tables in iOS 5 what is the best way to insert text fields?

Answer (score 0):

If the table has static content (number of rows and sections is constant) the easiest way is to add labels, text fields etc. right inside your storyboard or xib.